# Condensing list of changes to a smaller list

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am currently in the lookout for an algorithm that can help me condense a list of changes.

A change class looks like this

```
public class change
{
    DateTime From;
    DateTime To;
    string[] ChangedProperties;
}
```

Instances of this is then collected in list like this

```
string[] changes1 = {"A", "B", "C"};
string[] changes2 = {"D"};
string[] changes3 = {"A","B","C","E"};
string[] changes4 = {"A"};
string[] changes5 = {"B"};
string[] changes6 = {"B"};

Change first = new Change()
{
    From = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(2080, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    Active = changes1
};

Change second = new Change()
{
    From = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    Active = changes2
};

Change third = new Change()
{
    From = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    Active = changes3
};

Change fourth = new Change()
{
    From = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    Active = changes4
};

Change fifth = new Change()
{
    From = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    Active = changes5
};

Change sixth = new Change()
{
    From = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    To = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 00, 00),
    Active = changes6
};

List<Change> changes = new List<Change>();
changes.Add(first);
changes.Add(second);
changes.Add(third);
changes.Add(fourth);
changes.Add(fifth);
changes.Add(sixth);
```

I would like to condense this list such that changes that are reflected fully overlapping timewise.

ex.

`first` changes attribute  `{"A", "B", "C"}` in Datetime span 2008-1-1T00:00:00 to 2080-1-1T00:00:00 but the `sixth` change changes attribute B in datetime span 2008-1-1T00:00:00 to 2015-1-1T00:00:00. The information provided by the Sixth change is redundant as it is fully enclosed in the first change

```
first : |---------| 
Sixth : |------|
```

The condensed list should only contain

Changes: first, Second, (only change E from  third), fifth

This what I have so far:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ytlh7

Comment: Sort by start time then end end time, sweep left to right, if change `i+1`'s start time >= change `i`s start time `&&` change `i+1`s end time <= change `i`s end time, look into the properties of those 2 and merge as needed. This makes an `O(n log n)` algorithm.

Comment: @user1984 could you formalize this in some pseudo code?
Why not order like this?

`foreach(var change in changes.OrderByDescending(x => x.To - x.From).ThenByDescending(x => x.Active.Length))`

I would assume most will be able to fit into the largest one, and this less evaluation is needed?

Comment: @user1984

User approach would not work, It would create an extra B at the end which is covered by the first
01/01/2003 00:00:00
01/01/2008 00:00:00
B
01/01/2005 00:00:00
01/01/2008 00:00:00
A
01/01/2008 00:00:00
01/01/2010 00:00:00
D
01/01/2008 00:00:00
01/01/2015 00:00:00
B

Comment: you can use a segment tree for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I ended up doing it...

https://dotnetfiddle.net/OliMgt

Not sure whether this is efficient?